# Parsing public key with KeyFactory

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, jwt

i am trying to verify the signature of a token with JWT.
But I get an error on KeyFactory.generatePublic
"Error parsing public key".
I first tried to decode my json well because I received the error "Illegal base64 character" or "Invalid key format"
Can anyone help me, to understand what I am doing wrong?
Thank you

```
fun testSign(token: String)
{
var kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
var publicKeyB64 = "{\"kid\":\"1\",\"e\":\"AQAB\",\"kty\":\"RSA\",\"alg\":\"RS256\",\"n\":\"rXYc2Ehtb42R83kLIw56biI/ABOp03lzbYHdXI0caeliqP7KPOvaKQjQsCl84qmA7CIRTve4sBUq1Fp/zwMeyxMV5tvLIX2WIexf0OarA5S1ibU9xCD6LWzkdy1nhXeeDCeaN3fn3/7cdQIijII5YBKt0jTdqj9Sc48dguwObWkDbqFTYHf5DNn1qXDpvTCMON696eXJu+wzu3O+U8JBIR0XJyn2tcnrprkE5V+XCBGcLtG6W86r9m/aJptuCEP3L+nVx7CCPd0y/g9QgbtGTJT2CvgRlAzmVmbg9WgKHA4ZIXprvnGgXdu+gSNUB2JiQ3lqRxJgPkXlUb4M0EGH4Q==\",\"use\":\"sig\"}"
publicKeyB64 = publicKeyB64.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/')
publicKeyB64 = String(
    Base64.getEncoder()
        .encode(publicKeyB64.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
)
val decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyB64)
val spec = X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded)
val publicKey = kf.generatePublic(spec) as RSAPublicKey
print(publicKey)
try {
    var algorithm: Algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, null);
    var verifier: JWTVerifier = com.auth0.jwt.JWT.require(algorithm)
        .withIssuer("auth0")
        .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
    var jwtDecodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
} catch (exception: JWTVerificationException) {
    //Invalid signature/claims
    print(exception)
}
}
```

I also tried with another type of key, but I always get the same type of error when I try to create the public key

```
var publicKeyB64 = "MIICXAIBAAKBgQCUibP4fY2PA/sGMKMbU6usuIGcOAqgQjD6c2ylVo05Oz7pgjnE+O0l2MFRUYUGT5KKk/W+0cAXkxaQHE3n8A8X1mHT8eMDmWnzz0PeYjDE8LQmAw8RY2FnVKFAB36BIjdb5FsZmCk5QYKU5+nWLMqH/j/IR5AyX5wR2SMoslUg2QIDAQABAoGAeJ1s7638IhLIZtldyRXjRKi6ToFPV50IKodJxOSIXt3WE0V05ZaA84eUSxUYIOzCgRbuqVmnUz1USAdD18AecC8qc7tXTRALLy7q8fxklPwmGPUOvTFmI7gRMUnvcWrq1gySk3SKpj0YmWnuY9Xmd2+xoWLzUeFD1CROY5OTjIECQQDDlp1+Al7+duR0XyMlkWLIk0nIbkQ5zlTAEipzmaeTSOJi6YG3EMMz3AGuZb7tw6HFxWqeg1hyKJ+TcTM3WTdJAkEAwmrCDKE29n3wFOBKsZZFQbDgVOUXCBs2ubEI+ALe1DJU5BlfnrhJOINRCNgnwSFNbwxDTkDpR6J6Av2ElAvNEQJAV0dVvk5Wj50Ecz2lFHWdLD41taAnB9igDxnMIcvWcK4cf+ENhmCPiwvJIEa8/aLIBNYErvmTtVWVaBkirrc8KQJABr+z+sJB6S6X/fGHRkDkKJKeRvQo54QiUzHdENbwq0cQAVcMJbNZ/1c3oen2/1JLoNY5I+dG8dCnEaGBT65VMQJBAIDqH1Kqs5tb51cpt6h9ot31SUVud5pSML/babwp3pRs1s6poreym4PkAyRug0Dgcj1zVLt25TlOHvrL9r3Swq8="
```

i get error here

```
 val publicKey = kf.generatePublic(spec) as RSAPublicKey
```

java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: Error parsing public key

what am I doing wrong?
I see I've seen many scripts on the net that do the same thing

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your second key seems to be incorret.

If you want you can create an `RSAPublicKey` from `n` and `e` values that are present in your first example. You will need to extract those values from the json that you provided and do it as follows :

```
var e = "AQAB";
var n = "rXYc2Ehtb42R83kLIw56biI/ABOp03lzbYHdXI0caeliqP7KPOvaKQjQsCl84qmA7CIRTve4sBUq1Fp/zwMeyxMV5tvLIX2WIexf0OarA5S1ibU9xCD6LWzkdy1nhXeeDCeaN3fn3/7cdQIijII5YBKt0jTdqj9Sc48dguwObWkDbqFTYHf5DNn1qXDpvTCMON696eXJu+wzu3O+U8JBIR0XJyn2tcnrprkE5V+XCBGcLtG6W86r9m/aJptuCEP3L+nVx7CCPd0y/g9QgbtGTJT2CvgRlAzmVmbg9WgKHA4ZIXprvnGgXdu+gSNUB2JiQ3lqRxJgPkXlUb4M0EGH4Q==";
var eInt = BigInteger(1, Base64.getDecoder().decode(e))
var nInt = BigInteger(1, Base64.getDecoder().decode(n))

var spec = RSAPublicKeySpec(nInt, eInt)
val publicKey = kf.generatePublic(spec) as RSAPublicKey
print(publicKey)
```

which will print your public key.

Comment: The second key is a **private** key, not a public key, and although it _is_ ASN.1 it is the algorithm-specific format from [PKCS1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2) not the format used by Java for privatekeys which is [PKCS8](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5208#section-5). It is also 1024-bit, which is no longer considered secure for RSA.

Comment: @michalk thanks, i managed to get a public key but then i get exception when i go to verify  https://pl.kotl.in/NKxMwJb79